# Find an homeomorphism between these spaces

Tags: general-topology

I am searching for a function $f: B^n \rightarrow [-1,1]^n$ that is an homeomorphism.
I was considering

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{\|x\|_2}{\|x\|_{\infty}}, & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\
  0, & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}$

but it is not continous at x=0.
Can somebody help?

Comment: Sharing with us the meaning of $B$ would be a good idea.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think $B^n$ is the closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Me too, but I wish to know what the OP has to say about it.

Comment: Yes, my apologies. It's the n-dimensional closed ball with a radius of 1 and centered at the origin. This notation is commonly used in topology.

Comment: @Johndoe You might want to edit your post by writing/explaining all the relevant notation.

Comment: It also doesn't map to the set you say it sets. That function maps to the reals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there. What you have written down gives the ratio between $x$ and $f(x)$ (with $0$ as an expected special case). Multiplying any non-zero $x$ by that ratio gives you what you need:

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
  x\frac{\|x\|_2}{\|x\|_{\infty}}, & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\
  0, & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to do it for a part of the picture and gluing the homeomorphisms together. For $n=2$, take the top part of the ball. Send the coordinates $(r\cos t,r\sin t)$ to $(\cot t,r)$ (you want the radial proportionality to become vertical proportionality while maintaining the same angle). For other $n$, you can generalize this with whatever polar coordinates you have.